# Creating a new singly linked list in java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

How to remove the first node of a linked list and add to a new linked list in java?
I know removing and adding but, I'm confused how to transfer the data element from one node to the other.

Comment: Post your existing code and explain what it's doing and what you're having difficulty about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a school assignment, so I won't give you the actual code, but here is an overview of what you need to implement:

- Let's name your two linked lists `A` and `B` (I'm going to assume you're dealing with singly linked lists). You want to remove the first node of `A` and add it to the end of `B`
- First, you need to find the tail (last) node of `B`. It should have a field called `next` or something of that sort.
- Make `B.tail.next` point to the location that `A.head` references (the first node of A)
- Make `A.head` point to the location that `A.head.next` references (aka the second node of A)
- Set `B.tail.next` to NULL (keep in mind that `B.tail` has now been updated to point to the old first node of `A`).

That's it! Make sure you do these in the right order, or you may overwrite a pointer that you need.

Comment: @LakshmanPalli Yeah the site is a little tough in the beginning, but it gets better. Also, if you think my answer is suitable, can you please accept it? (green checkmark)

Comment: Yes, thank you, fella. I should dive in more and a lot to cover.